# Discriminant of $x^4 - 7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, discriminant

According to the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_4) on the wikipedia page, the discriminant of $x^4 - 7$ should be 0. But the polynomial has roots $\pm \sqrt[4]{7}$ and $\pm i\sqrt[4]{7}$ so it is separable, so it shouldn't have zero discriminant. What's going on?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant+of+x%5E4-7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the term $256a^3e^3$, which is nonzero, and all other terms are zero.

Comment: Ah, I am an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Since $b=c=d=0$, the discriminant is:
$$ \Delta=256 a^3 e^3 $$
In your case, you have $a=1$, $e=-7$, so:
$$ \Delta = 256 \cdot (-7)^3 = -87808 \neq 0$$